# Qt Linux filemapping for global memory

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-memory

So I need to write file mapping (Windows `OpenFileMapping()`, `MapViewOfFile()`, etc) for Linux. I chose `QSharedMemory` for this.
But I'm not sure how to make it work with global memory.

Is there another correct file mapping anolog for Linux or features of `QSharedMemory`?

Comment: Just use it from Boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The QSharedMemory is for creating a shared memory between processes, not for memory mapping a file. (See the official Qt [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-ipc-sharedmemory-example.html)).

For a memory mapped file, you can simply use the `.map()` function on a QFile, e.g.

```
QFile file("MyFile");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
     //handle error
}
uchar *memory = file.map(0, file.size());
if (memory) {
    //mapped ok, use memory here

    file.unmap();
} else {
   //handle error
}
```

The `.map()` function is inherited from a [QFileDevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#map). By default the mapping is shared between other processes, you can use the `QFileDevice::MapPrivateOption` to create a private mapping where changes to the mapped memory are not shared with other processes(or the disk file).

Answer (score 2):

`QSharedMemory` is more suited to attaching to SysV shared memory objects.  It sounds like you're looking more for a C++ wrapper around memory-mapped files (judging from the names of the functions you quote - I don't know any Windows APIs).

I've had success in the past using `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source` (for a read-only mapping of the file):

```
// compiled, but not actually tested!

#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

void useMappedFile(QString filename)
{
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source file(filename.toStdString());
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        qWarning() << "Failed to open file";
        return;
    }

    auto bytes = QByteArray::fromRawData(file.data(), file.size());

    someFunction(bytes);

    // do not allow 'file' to go out of scope before 'bytes', as it owns the
    // storage!  Read the description of 'QByteArray::fromRawData'.
}
```

There's also `mapped_file_sink` and `mapped_file` in the same namespace, for write-only and read-write mappings respectively.

Comment: You may also want to investigate `QFileDevice::map`, but I have no relevant experience to share here.  It looks like a very thin wrapper around the standard `mmap()` function.

Comment: Thank you for code example! I actually don't really know, how to point to read (or create) file in global, not local memor, now I'll bevblooking in boost library.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'global memory'.  If you simply mean that several processes can share a single mapping of a file, then read the section on `MAP_SHARED` in the `mmap()` manpage.  I'm not sure how to pass that on to `mapped_file_source`, though.

Comment: A lower-level approach is to use `mmap()` directly, and create a smart pointer with `munmap()` as its deleter.  Perhaps useful if you can't get `MAP_SHARED` into boost `mapped_file`...